# NPM & Bower update/install/prune all in one?

Tags: npm, bower, npm-install, bower-install

I got tired of running npm and bower install/update/prune commands, every time someone from my team made a change to the project.

Now, if I pay attention to what exactly they changed, and if they even changed either package.json or bower.json, then I could maybe not have to do all 6 commands... But, honestly, it was easier to just type those 6 than to check what people changed, especially when there are quite a few files touched...

So, I wanted to find a way to do all 6 with just one command.
And I haven't found it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a tool for that: [updatejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/updatejs).

Answer (score 0):

Thats nice! I integrated it my projects and it works fine :)

Comment: This should have been a comment on the other answer.